# graph datawindow shows error when procedure is changed in power builder

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I have a `userobject` where I have used graph `datawindow` in it. Can I change the procedure in that graph `datawindow` without recreating `datawindow`? I tried using syntax

```
 datawindow.table.procedure = <procedure name>
```

But I got an error telling **error accessing external object property procedure**..

Answer (score 0):

From the PB Help on the datawindow it appears as though you need to use the modify syntax similar to:

```
dw_l.Modify (" DataWindow.Table.Procedure= &
   '1 Execute MyOwner MyProcName;1  &
  @NameOfProcArg=:NameOfDWArg, &
  @NameOfProcArg=:NameOfDWArg...' ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask clearly about procedure change:

- procedure change = change to new name/ new sp, or
- change the content of the script your sp, this I can help you, **the solution is right click the object and choose regenerate, this trick can use for other dw use sp.**

Happy coding from PB Developer.